# Making fur soft at tips? It is coming out as bristly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

I rarely use the particle system, but I am trying to replicate this type of fur in Blender 3.2. However, the fur no longer fades into a soft and fluffy end like this Blender 2.79 particle system does... it only turns out coarse and harsh. I have played with many settings, yet none seem to do the trick. It may be a simple solution, but I have no idea... any help?

(I am using Cycles as well)

[image]          <-- This is the type of fur I would like to achieve

[image]   <-- This is what comes out when I render in 3.2

I am aware the file is designed for an older version of Blender, but I bet there is a way to reproduce the fur in the newer versions

Comment: Looks like Children -> Clumping is set to 1 and should be closer to 0

Comment: as Allen says, I suppose that you need to play a bit with the Children > Clumping and Roughness values